# DFM accepting sum of ab* and ba*

Tags: automata

I have a problem with task:
Draw a diagram of the deterministic finite state machine accepting the sum of languages marked with regular expressions ab* and ba*.

I resolve task:
Draw a diagram of the deterministic state finite machine accepting the concatenation languages marked with the regular expression ab* and ba*.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X4hrCSbuqCcNOx1p9AQLkgmoRe06F27N/view?usp=sharing

but I have no idea how to do it for a sum.
Please for help.
Best regards !

Comment: By sum do you mean concatenation?

Comment: Yeah sum of concatenation languages

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to MSE!

You mean $ab^*\cup ba^*$ (sum as union).
The automaton graph has a common starting state $s_0$. Then there are transitions $s_0\stackrel{a}{\rightarrow} s_a$ and $s_0\stackrel{b}{\rightarrow} s_b$ and loops
$s_a\stackrel{b}{\rightarrow} s_a$ and $s_b\stackrel{a}{\rightarrow} s_b$, where $s_a,s_b$ are the final states.

Comment: it will be the same as what I sent in the link only without the trash.
This diagram is supposed to be without a trash? Best regards !